# Azure static web app functions return error 503

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

We have a few services running on SWA and suddenly we get error 503 from all of them when accessing the funtions. There are no announced issues reported in Azure portal. Since we have the issue with multiple subscriptions, this seem to be a global issue.
Does anybody else have the same problem or any idea to what might be the issue?

We have tried to deploy all code again (CI/CD github) without success

Comment: works for me... if that answers your question ;) Sorry, you need to provide a lot more detail to your question in order for anybody here to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There was a backend service issue with Azure Static Web App yesterday. It was recovered and worked normally after a few hours. There were some HTTP 503 errors and failed to load the functions for SWA apps. Today it's back to work normally.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5WnQ.jpg